# How to trigger code on another page on button click?

Tags: php, html, button

I have a two pages, first carries a `button` and second some php code. All I want to do is trigger code on page two at clicking button on page one. I don't want to open page two as it has no `body` or `html` elements, all it has is just `php` code and I just want to trigger that. How to do that?

Let button be:

```
<button class="show"></button>
```

Comment: there are tons of questions about this here, put some effort into searching

Comment: @Nordenheim better add a link I could't find one.

Comment: AJAX is your way to fly :)

Answer (score 0):

sounds like it would suit your situation better to place the script on the same page then execute it when post has a value.

like this.

```
    <?php 
        if (!empty($_POST))
        {
         //CODE TO BE EXECUTED
        }
    ?>

 <form method="post" action="">
   <input type="submit" value="button" name="submit">
 </form>
```